# PHP : couldn't replace using preg_replace()

Tags: php

Just I'm replacing the object tag in the given string

```
$matches = preg_replace("/<object(.+?)</object>/","replacing string",$str);
```

but it is showing the error as

```
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'o'
```

What went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The slash in `</object>` has to be quoted: `<\/object>`, or else it is interpreted as the end of your regex since you're delimiting it with slashes. The whole line should read:

```
$matches = preg_replace("/<object(.+?)<\\/object>/","replacing string",$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your regex the forward slash is the regex delimiter. As you are dealing with tags, better use another delimiter (instead of escaping it with a backslash):

```
$matches = preg_replace("#<object(.+?)</object>#", "replacing string", $str);
```

There are other delimiteres, too. You can use any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character. However, certain delimiters should not be used under any circumstances: `|`, `+`, `*` and parentheses/brackets for example as they are often used in the regular expressions and would just confuse people and make them hate you.

Btw, using regular expressions for HTML is a [***Bad Thing***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)!

Answer (score 0):

The first character is taken as delimiter char to separate the expression from the flags. Thus this:

```
"/[a-z]+/i"
```

... is internally split into this:

```
- Pattern: [a-z]+
- Flags: i
```

So this:

```
"/<object(.+?)</object>/"
```

... is not a valid regexp. Try this:

```
"@<object(.+?)</object>@"
```